# Ajax form an multi-select

Tags: forms, 8

I have a form which provides select2 when the select1 is changed. However I would like select2 to be a multi-select. I can't seem to get this to work. It populates a single select input just fine, but not the multi-select. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $options = NULL) {
  $form['expeditions'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Choose Project'),
    '#empty_option' => $this->t('Select a project'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => '::getDeployments',
      'wrapper' => 'deployment-wrapper',
    ],
  ];

  // Disable caching on this form.
  $form_state->setCached(FALSE);

  $form['deployment_wrapper'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => ['id' => 'deployment-wrapper'],
  ];

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
}

public function getDeployments(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $expedition_id = $form_state->getValue('expeditions');
  if ($expedition_id != "") {
    $arms_config = \Drupal::config('arms.settings');
    $rest_root = $arms_config->get("arms_rest_uri");

    $client = \Drupal::service('http_client');
    try {
      $result = $client->get(
        $rest_root . 'arms/projects/' . $expedition_id,
        ['Accept' => 'application/json']
      );
      $expedition = json_decode($result->getBody());
    }
    catch (RequestException $e) {
      watchdog_exception('arms', $e);
      drupal_set_message('Error fetching project.', 'error');
    }
  }

  $options = [];

  foreach ($expedition->{'deployments'} as $deployment_id) {
    array_push($options, $deployment_id);
  }

  $form['deployment_wrapper']['deployments'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Choose Deployment(s)'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
  ];

  return $form['deployment_wrapper'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a select element in an ajax callback, because the form builder needs to know about it.

Move all code from ajax callback to buildFrom(). Make this code conditional on form_state.

Your callback contains only:

```
return $form['deployment_wrapper'];
```